# UV map slightly distorted for some reason

Tags: uv

so I've been working on a mod for a videogame but I ran into a problem that I simply can't figure out on my own (I'm fairly new to blender but I honestly don't know what I've been doing wrong). So I modeled the object (an I-beam, pretty basic stuff -->started from a cube and added some edge-loops and did some extrusion and scaling) applied the scale and location and started to place the seams. Then I duplicated the object b/c I've been planning to bake a normal map later on. After that, I unwrapped the model but there always is this one part or rather loop of the unwrapped model which appears to be deformed for some odd reason. I don't know but I don't think it has anything to do with my placement of the seams but I might be mistaken. Anyway, I'd appreciate your help and please let me know if you need further information:)[image][image][image]

Comment: could you share the object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: wow didn't expect a reply so soon but yeah sure

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=e3v6vdN8" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/e3v6vdN8/)

Comment: I don't see the door, could you please just share the door?

Comment: there is no door just a vertical i-beam and a horizontal one but those are separate objects...the horizontal one is hidden and I haven't yet started to unwrap it so pay it no mind

Comment: oh my bad the object i was refering to in the post is the beam HV LP....i edited the file and hid it sorry

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=OW0allsm" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/OW0allsm/)

Comment: I guess it's because your beam is not square, it gets larger on its top, but anyway why does it bother you? is it just a theoretical question?

Comment: Well as I said earlier I tried to bake a normal on the low poly mesh of said mesh and I had some trouble with it (normal map looks kinda weird) and since I tried it before on a screw in the same blend file without having any problems I thought it might be because of the UV map distortion. Also, the beam gets larger by choice. anyway, thanks for the quick reply  :)

Comment: yes but the fact that the beam gets larger makes the distortion because the border of the horizontal face is not straight and the other one can't overlap this one, so it goes obliquely. Also, about the bake, maybe tell what's the problem. With angular object it won't be able to catch the faces that will be parallel to the normals, maybe that's the problem...

Comment: mhm yeah, that might be it...the normal map looks weird where the angled faces are...is there anything I can do about it except making the beam straight?

Comment: so there are 2 problems: your UV map and the bake. For the UV map, if you want it to be straight, I guess you need to put an edge loop somewhere so that the top part is square and won't tilt the face. For the bake, as I said a bake can't catch a surface that is completely parallel to the normal direction, so you need to slightly shrink some faces. If it's not clear I can try to illustrate both these 2 points (tomorrow though).

Comment: Oh an illustration would be nice if it won't cause you any inconvenience. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

About your distorted UV map:

it comes from the fact that your beam is actually enlarging on its top, so the faces are not perpendicular. The consequence is that it will stretch the UV map in the *UV Editor*: Blender just tries to find an average arrangement between faces, it doesn't know that it needs to give priority to perpendicular angles. I've made a second test with perpendicular faces and as you see it works fine.

What you could do though is making the UV map orthogonal with some addons, or: first unwrap the top part, then the bottom, then in the *UV Editor*, make the bottom faces stick to the top faces with the help of the snap.

[image]

About your Bake problem:

There might be several reasons, it really depends on your problem. I guess one of your problems is that your object is made of 90° perpendicular angles. In that case you need to know that, as the ray of the baking follows a direction that is perpendicular to the face normal, it won't be able to record any of the faces that are completely parallel or perpendicular... the baking will be completely "blank". Whereas if you slightly tilt those parallel faces the ray will hurt them and therefore they will be seen (the perpendicular face won't be seen but it doesn't matter, the parallel faces will give the illusion of deepness).

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks i think i got it now....about the normals man i'm such an idiot haha...i knew that and did the same thing you did when i modeled and baked the screw but for some reason forgot about it when i modeled the beam